# SUM() multiple Time values together in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to add multiple Time values together but I am at a loss on how to do that. Lets say I have a table with a column 'MyTime' and I have 4 rows with the values (for example..could be anything):

06:55:00

07:54:00

06:52:00

08:05:00

How do I write a SELECT query to get the total time added up? I would like to keep the 'time structure' (MM:SS) format if I can. Milliseconds arent a big deal if they are there or not.

**If this is not possible or WAAAY too hard then I guess I could have the column be the seconds and add them, but then I will need some assistance on how to go from seconds to a MM:SS format

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Blindly tried SELECT SUM(MyTime) but that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(**time_column_name**)) as timeTotal FROM **time_table_name**
```

Use the timeTotal result for the total

Comment: It doesnt recognize the function 'SEC_TO_TIME'